# Can't get DNSSEC correct answer

Tags: security, dns, python

I have a DNS server for `com` zone. I configured DNSSEC based on this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-dnssec-on-an-authoritative-bind-dns-server--2)

In short, I created Zone Siging Key (ZSK) and Key Signing Key (KSK). I have signed the zone using the command:

```
sudo dnssec-signzone -A -3 $(head -c 1000 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16) -N INCREMENT -o com -t forward.com
```

This part of the command for random slat:

```
head -c 1000 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16
```

I have the following forward.com.signed (NOTE: I ommitted the full signature string - just show the first line for brevity):

```
; File written on Thu May 24 02:13:50 2018
; dnssec_signzone version 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu
com.            604800  IN SOA  dns1.com. admin.com. (
                    33         ; serial
                    604820     ; refresh (1 week 20 seconds)
                    86600      ; retry (1 day 3 minutes 20 seconds)
                    2419600    ; expire (4 weeks 6 minutes 40 seconds)
                    604600     ; minimum (6 days 23 hours 56 minutes 40 seconds)
                    )
            604800  RRSIG   SOA 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    Qfd9i1AndX/dmyQuksOo2CRXH5RyM7i52c3P )
            604800  NS  dns1.com.
            604800  RRSIG   NS 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    Qj1DMmEhfkU5KI9MVrIlgKmQ5DxTjGuRNJ8i)
            604800  DNSKEY  256 3 7 (
                    AwEAAfZWrsuiFoAAGcOTDWyVlDoZjQC8CZc6) ; ZSK; alg = NSEC3RSASHA1; key id = 12410
            604800  DNSKEY  257 3 7 (
                    AwEAAbc92MYUBPIs1L6lNAbubqRmZCfgv1h7) ; KSK; alg = NSEC3RSASHA1; key id = 62649
            604800  RRSIG   DNSKEY 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    MuNVIE6oWV03+dXnXu+VufPQqfIgQvNIBODh)
            604800  RRSIG   DNSKEY 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 62649 com.
                    HxKx8nsyZ/qtrAvhsFJ9r7EBBwhSCGh0FJfM)
            0   NSEC3PARAM 1 0 10 1C5A91FD094B6845
            0   RRSIG   NSEC3PARAM 7 1 0 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    qXpHn0q2GG/BK71mMYqCELsoHiFT6Oel82Jv)
dns1.com.       604800  IN A    192.168.56.3
            604800  RRSIG   A 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    aHB7ZCD8dDV4jMHJsUg23jjcm48tTnUvS8hy )
a.com.      604800  IN A    192.168.56.7
            604800  RRSIG   A 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    0V7mUWUOuru41Rkp+RFp6eV13AHOdPnEanrV)
            604800  TXT "some-random-text"
            604800  RRSIG   TXT 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    Uta2/oGszVJAhm/DlGd7vnD+irg/GzyXlKHp)
b.com.      604800  IN A    192.168.56.8
            604800  RRSIG   A 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    2ui9x3SjrrEvFkcPbfcfC/NQW0MQOv2jy/Bd)
            604800  TXT ""
            604800  RRSIG   TXT 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    etX8lM00XXK9hUMM4FVsc51zuYOCz2+6qNLM)
8NRLOA7UP8TGKLFJ7A6KPTIS503NJ4NB.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    QNU3FGJ5VOCSBIP3N93ITKLM4OP6GMCO
                    A TXT RRSIG )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    0qFfv4wr6WYSb4JlrtOlmPWykmCUKNdADlH8)
QNU3FGJ5VOCSBIP3N93ITKLM4OP6GMCO.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    TVQJ9TFT4DPK7IGFE32TKLFG6EH2CUH5
                    A RRSIG )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    qZCi11tgJWJwjK2NI9KTVkcaJ0Eln0NVDsjM)
TVQJ9TFT4DPK7IGFE32TKLFG6EH2CUH5.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    0J67JF0QNUUEKT5VF6FQPCRR9T8I8RT7
                    NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    gud9iAHIRi4vR6eCgwOe6Xz0fR5F1qksJz6x)
0J67JF0QNUUEKT5VF6FQPCRR9T8I8RT7.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    8NRLOA7UP8TGKLFJ7A6KPTIS503NJ4NB
                    A TXT RRSIG )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    8ZowNBjQXgaAx89kjTmgCu/9lYLk14L+xTWr)
```

Then I tested by DNS server using a python client that uses dnspython library:

```
import dns.name
import dns.query
import dns.dnssec
import dns.message
import dns.resolver
import dns.rdatatype


resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
nameServer = resolver.nameservers = ['192.168.56.3'] # our local private DNS server
nsaddr = '192.168.56.3'

# get DNSKEY for zone
request = dns.message.make_query('com.',
                                 dns.rdatatype.DNSKEY,
                                 want_dnssec=True)

# send the query
response = dns.query.udp(request,nsaddr)
print(str(response))
```

As you can see there is not answer in the output:

```
id 13728
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR AA TC RD RA
edns 0
eflags DO
payload 4096
;QUESTION
com. IN DNSKEY
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

**Can you please help me figure out what is the problem?**

**EDIT:**
I used dig and got this answer if this may help you point to me where is the problem?

```
x@x:/etc/bind$ dig +multiline COM DNSKEY

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +multiline COM DNSKEY
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31782
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;COM.           IN DNSKEY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
COM.            83148 IN DNSKEY 256 3 8 (
                AQOz+iBqxZtCKBBqKsO/i9JVchZ2Z1pFCWnj+pFHJi3u
                PWiYWsAMvtMpInRPfV1Ot9m+8nHPxSkvOL2+bttj4jEK
                6uUfTarET4wAMSh2k9rX2h+9kVQDjcuRwfFXV5bAmFd3
                j57hic7FEYVSxXtNUVU7BPaFRHuFr3OrQHQXaR4IeQ==
                ) ; ZSK; alg = RSASHA256; key id = 36707
COM.            83148 IN DNSKEY 257 3 8 (
                AQPDzldNmMvZFX4NcNJ0uEnKDg7tmv/F3MyQR0lpBmVc
                NcsIszxNFxsBfKNW9JYCYqpik8366LE7VbIcNRzfp2h9
                OO8HRl+H+E08zauK8k7evWEmu/6od+2boggPoiEfGNyv
                NPaSI7FOIroDsnw/taggzHRX1Z7SOiOiPWPNIwSUyWOZ
                79VmcQ1GLkC6NlYvG3HwYmynQv6oFwGv/KELSw7ZSdrb
                TQ0HXvZbqMUI7BaMskmvgm1G7oKZ1YiF7O9ioVNc0+7A
                SbqmZN7Z98EGU/Qh2K/BgUe8Hs0XVcdPKrtyYnoQHd2y
                nKPcMMlTEih2/2HDHjRPJ2aywIpKNnv4oPo/
                ) ; KSK; alg = RSASHA256; key id = 30909

;; Query time: 1219 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu May 24 10:16:44 BST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 452
```

Comment: dig output comes from `127.0.1.1`, where you script uses `192.168.56.3`, so without further explanations, the two are not querying necessarily the same nameserver... Also you shouldn't use valid existing TLD for whatever you are doing, you will only get problems. Register any given domain name and use it as suffix for all your internal domain names needs.