# How to check if DNSSEC is correct in my DNS server?

Tags: networking, security, dns

I have a local DNS server (BIND 9.10). I just configured DNSEC, but I am facing problems at the client-side (python script).

How can I test if my DNS server is configured correctly? That the DNSSEC is correct?

EDIT:
I am running an authoritative server and want to sign my own zone. My zone name is `com`. I have two servers, say: `a.com` and `b.com.`

I am running a resolver (at the client-side using python dnspython), and I want to validate received signatures?

I want to make a simple setting. I do not need the trust chain. The client just wants to check the authenticity of the Zone Signing Key (ZSK) using the DNS Key Signing Key (KSK).  No higher levels of validation needed in my set-up.

More about my zone signed file, and my client can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1325499/cant-get-dnssec-correct-answer) and another more technical one in [stack-overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501005/dnssec-using-dnspython-error-attributeerror-ns-object-has-no-attribute-is-a). Please let me know if you need more details. I also cut the full signature from my posts for brevity and use general names of the servers: `a.com` and `b.com` for privacy.

Comment: That's about as specific as "I configured the internet." How do you want to use DNSSEC? Are you running an authoritative server and want to sign your own zone? Are you running a resolver and want to validate received signatures? Are you trying to use DNSSEC for authenticating zone transfers or dynamic updates?

Comment: @grawity please check my edit. I hope you can help and please let me know if you have more questions in order to help me.

Comment: @grawity one more important question I have, where should I save the keys? I am placing them in: `/etc/bind` where the zone file and the `.signed` zone file are.

Comment: The exact location doesn't matter (with BIND even the zone locations aren't quite standardized), as long as they're readable by BIND itself but not readable by other users of course. I suppose `/etc/bind` is okay.

Comment: @grawity Could you figure out the original post problem?

Answer (score 1):

https://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/ this might help? Run the domain through this. Will not work if the server is NOT on WAN

Comment: It is a private network with private IPs (not public) so online tools will not recognize it.

Comment: Awwf. Well, as i expected, but i googled a little and found this tool: https://www.dnssec-tools.org/ inside here you have a link to a download. I have not tested or checked the link by myself but i would make it a try. Looks legit for me.